# Efficiency of std::get with std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm curious as to the lookup time that a call to `std::get<>` on a `std::tuple<>` takes.  Some brief googling (including the reference pages which usually have this information) turned up no results.

My initial intuition (and fear) is that the recursive structure of tuple (if it is implemented as a variadic template) would lead to get requiring an order of N lookups (A call to `get<3>(t)` looking like `t.rest().rest().first()`.  I'm hoping I'm way off here...

Then again, I would hope the compiler would be able to optimize this to directly return the correct offset without the overhead of N of calls.

Basically what I want: is there a specced guarantee on runtime? does this restrict how `std::tuple` is implemented?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The C++ specification does not provide a guarantee on the runtime performance of *any* function. Even when it states asymptotic requirements, that only guarantees the relative number of operations, not the performance of those operations. O(1) doesn't mean fast, nor does O(n) mean slow.

You can either trust your compiler/optimizer/standard library implementation, or you can rewrite it all yourself to get whatever performance you want. `std::get`, under most reasonable compilers (with optimizations on), should perform more or less equivalently to directly accessing the value from a struct. But the spec doesn't require that at any point.

Comment: The relevant section of the Standard here is **1.9 Program execution [intro.execution]** "1 The semantic descriptions in this International Standard deﬁne a parameterized nondeterministic abstract machine. This International Standard places no requirement on the structure of conforming implementations. In particular, they need not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine. Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained
below.5"

Answer (score 21):

The efficiency will be comparable to accessing a member of a struct. The `get<>` is resolved at compile time.

Comment: Can you point me at spec? Could you explain this in detail? What enables this? inlining?

Comment: This is enabled by template resolution, performed during compilation. At runtime, the code resolves to reading from the object's address + a shift (and hence similar to accessing a member of a `struct`).

Comment: @AnthonySottile You can always check the generated assembly and see that's what it's doing.

Comment: I don't see anything in the standard that requires `std::get<>` to be implemented efficiently, and I can imagine legitimate reasons why it might not be (debugging).

Comment: @hvd: There's nothing in the standard that requires *anything* to be implemented "efficiently" (even O(1) operations can be inefficiently implemented). If you're going to spend a lot of time second-guessing your compiler or standard library implementation, you're not going to actually get much done. It's reasonable to expect inlining and RVO to make the call little more than a struct access in an optimized build.

Comment: @NicolBolas Considering the question *specifically asks* "is there a specced guarantee on runtime", if the spec doesn't guarantee what this answer claims, then this isn't an answer, but it would be a useful answer to another question for the reasons you give.

Comment: @hvd the spec doesn't guarantee MAX PERFOMANZ anywhere. It puts constraints on certain operations. There is no magic quote from the Standard that will give a mathematical proof for every implementation. Also, RVO is so 2000.

Comment: @rubenvb: RVO is 2000? Oh my... it was standard practice when *The C++ memory model* was written back in 1995! (and yet it's still current)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas lol, RVO has lost its shininess when move semantics came along, save for the objects with a byte count you can count on your fingers(/hands? -> English language translator failure).

Comment: @utnapistim, I don't know of any `tuple` implementation that does it like that. A typical implementation puts each element in a base class `tuple_base<N, ...>`, with each base having a different `N`, then `std::get<1>(t)` is as "simple" as causing an implicit conversion to `tuple_base<1, ...>` to select that base. For some value of simple.

Comment: @JonathanWakely - yes, but this is done by the compiler. In runtime, this should evaluate to `tuple_base<N, ...>::tuple_base<N-1, ...>::...tuple_base<0, ...>::value` or something like that.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean about a runtime shift being needed now ... I would still say it's a purely compile-time operation though

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the first question (how long `std::get` takes) depends on how your library chooses to implement `std::tuple` and `std::get`.  But typically, libraries will choose to use a non-recursive approach, similar to the one outlined here: http://mitchnull.blogspot.com/2012/06/c11-tuple-implementation-details-part-1.html.  With that type of approach, the access time of `std::get` will be constant, and roughly equivalent to the time it takes to access a member of a struct.

In answer to whether the standard provides any guarantees: as others have said, no, the standard makes no guarantees here.  An evil library writer could choose to make `std::get` exponential in N, and they'd still be standard-compliant.